# finding the MAX value in a count

Tags: mysql, max

My code is

```
$query = "SELECT teamID, season,
    MAX(season) AS current_season,
    COUNT(DISTINCT matchID AND season=current_season) AS season_games_played,
    FROM finances
    WHERE teamID = '$_SESSION[teamID]'";
```

but this gives me an error :(

What I am trying to do is get the amount of games that the team has played this season, so current_season is to be the MAX value of column season.

My next line of code is to find out how many games the team played last season (MAX(season)-1) I assume, but how would this be written?

Comment: remove the comma after season_games_played and then try it.
What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way of doing this would probably be

```
SELECT
     season,
       COUNT(DISTINCT matchID) AS season_games_played
    FROM finances
    WHERE teamID = '$_SESSION[teamID]' /*<-- Probable SQL injection risk!*/
    GROUP BY season
    ORDER BY season DESC
    LIMIT 2;
```

I have removed `teamID` from the `SELECT` list as you are already passing that in so know that already.

I assume `'$_SESSION[teamID]'` is php or something. Please read up on how to avoid SQL injection in that language.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Have read up on sql injection and there is no chance they can do it there, it's a computer generated number.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    teamID,
    season,
    COUNT(DISTINCT matchID) AS season_games_played,
FROM finances
WHERE teamID = ?
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

The first row will be the most recent season, the 2nd row will be the 2nd most recent season etc.